# Did the giving of the Law on Mount Sinai occur on Shavuot?

Tags: law, feasts

by Saber Truth Tiger

In Exodus chapters 19 and 20 we read of the giving of the Law at Mount Sinai. Many believe this momentous event occurred during the first week of Sivan, the third month in the Hebrew calendar (see Exodus 19:1). Many Jewish scholars claim this event happened on Shavuot, the third annual feast day in the Jewish calendar. In today's fixed Jewish calendar that is always Sivan 6 (and also Sivan 7 outside of Israel).

However, before the creation of the fixed calendar in the fourth century CE, the first day of the month began when observers appointed by the Sanhedrin spotted the thin crescent of the moon in the western sky as the sun was setting. This means that months could vary, either 29 or 30 days each. No months had 31 days because if the crescent still hadn't been spotted on the evening of the 30th day, the new day would be declared the first day of the month.

A prelude to Shavuot was the feast of the Passover in the first month of the Jewish calendar. In the Jewish calendar, Passover fell on Abib 14 and the first feast day of the Passover fell on the next day. Rabbinical Judaism calls this feast day (Abib or Nisan 15) an annual Sabbath, of which there were seven every year. Current Jewish tradition holds the countdown toward Shavuot began with a 50-day countdown that began on the day after the annual Sabbath (Abib 16). If we assume that Abib had 30 days and Iyyar had 29 days, then Sivan 6 would be the 50th day since Abib 16, the day of the rabbinical waving of the Omer.

However, the Sadducees in the first century CE and the modern Karaites reckon the 50-day countdown differently than the Rabbis. They do not count down from the day after the annual Sabbath but the day after the first *weekly* Sabbath during the Days of Unleavened Bread. Hence, with Sadducee and Karaite  inclusive counting, Shavuot would always fall on a Sunday.
Under Sadducee's and Karaite's reckoning, there could be several days between the observance of the Passover meal and the first weekly Sabbath of the week-long Passover festival. Under their reckoning, Shavuot would always fall on a Sunday but it would also fall on a different day of the month of Sivan every year.

There are those who disagree with this and they have reasons why they disagree. Historian and author Daniel Gregg has written an article on the subject of Karaite's belief that Shavuot always falls on Sunday. His article required a lot of study so I thought I would offer everyone a chance to see his reasons for rejecting the Karaite position. Gregg maintains that the first Shavuot ever fell on the weekly Sabbath in the year of the Exodus.

https://www.torahtimes.org/CalendarChaos.html

This is a little odd because he elsewhere claims the Omer is waved on the day after the annual Sabbath (Nisan 16) as the Pharisees did but he believes the seven Sabbath countdown toward Shavuot begins on the first weekly Sabbath after the waving of the Omer. The difference between the two is Daniel Gregg believes the waving of the Omer comes after the first so-called annual Sabbath and before the first weekly Sabbath of the days of Unleavened Bread. Gregg then begins his seven Sabbath countdown from the *first* weekly Sabbath of Passover week.

Under the Sadducean and Karaite reckoning, however, the waving of the Omer occurs on the day after the first weekly Sabbath in the Feast of Unleavened Bread. This would be Sunday. This Sunday is day one of the beginning of the seven Sabbath countdown towards Shavuot. The first of the seven Sabbaths falls on the following Saturday. Gregg's so-called "first of the Sabbaths" falls a week earlier than the Sadducee and Karaite reckoning.

It is claimed by some historians that during Jesus' time on earth, the Pharisees controlled Temple Worship, and the Pharisees counting the seven weeks to Shavuot began the day after the first "annual Sabbath" no matter which day of the week it occurred. This would be Nisan 16. Then, the Pharisees would count the seven Sabbath (week) countdown from that same day. Hence, under their reckoning, they did not count seven Sabbaths, they instead counted seven WEEKS, even if the countdown began on a Tuesday, they would count seven weeks (and not Sabbaths) and the fiftieth day would fall on Tuesday. The same would apply if the Omer was waved on a Thursday. Fifty days later Shavuot would fall on a Thursday.

I discussed in another answer some of the reasons why I don't believe the giving of the Law occurred on Shavuot. Here is the link to those reasons:

[What is the correct date the Israelites arrived at Sinai?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/what-is-the-correct-date-the-israelites-arrived-at-sinai/77435#77435)

Under Sadducean and Karaite reckoning Shavuot would fall on Sunday. Under Pharisee and rabbinical reckoning, Shavuot could fall on any day of the week, including the weekly Sabbath.

Those who claim the giving of the Law fell on the weekly Sabbath must admit IF Shavuot fell on that day, then it was the rabbinical reckoning of the feasts and counting that was in use and not the Sadducean reckoning. The argument fails however because Shavuot didn't even exist at that time. In the year of the Exodus the weekly Sabbath wasn't even revealed until weeks after the departure from Egypt. Likewise, there was no waving of the Omer that year and therefore no seven Sabbath countdown to Shavuot. The first waving of the Omer did not even begin until the children of Israel entered the Promised Land some 40 years later.

So my question is did the giving of the Law occur on Shavuot or did it not? Am I correct or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct date the Israelites arrived at Sinai?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/what-is-the-correct-date-the-israelites-arrived-at-sinai)

Comment: The plain reading of Ex 19:1 suggests that it was 59 days after leaving Egypt, that is after Passover.

Comment: The plain reading of Ezodus 19:1 is not as plain as you seem to think. There are several different translations of Ezodus 19:1. The literal translation may be elusive. https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Exodus%2019:1

Comment: @Dottard What date do you believe Passover occurred? Where do you get that the giving of the Law occurred 59 days later?

Comment: @Dottard I have been taught all my life that Ezodus 19:1 referred to the first day of the moon. I may be wrong. I am open to another theory if you can prove it to me. I will change my opinion if necessary.

Comment: Ex 19:1 simply states "in the 3rd moon ... on this day .." This could be construed to mean either the first of Sivan or exactly two months after Passover, namely the 15th day of Sivan.  The former gives 45/46 days travel, the latter gives 59 days travel.  If one insists on the former, then Pentecost was a few days after that.

Comment: I meant to say the first day of the third moon, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145565/discussion-between-dottard-and-saber-truth-tiger).

Comment: @Dottard Due to the many possible translations of this verse I do not find it a plain reading or "simply states". How do you decide which one to use? I use what I have been taught all my life as "the third moon" which (I was taught) without a designation of a day automatically meant the first day of the month. I could very well be in error so give me your case for the 15th day of Sivan.

Comment: See my replies in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145565/discussion-between-dottard-and-saber-truth-tiger

Comment: A good question, to which there is no good answer.